# Flutter Textfield Validation message indexing

Tags: flutter

I have one form in Flutter, with simple textfield and validation messages.

In textfield there are placeholders which slide up when user focus in particular textfield. at that time if there is a validation message from above field, then placeholder is showing above the validation message.

Here is the Screenshot

[image]

### Here is my Code

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("This is App Bar"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.00),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.00),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      child: Stack(
                    overflow: Overflow.visible,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 0.0,
                        top: 45.0,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 5, right: 5, top: 1, bottom: 3),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0),
                                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(5.0)),
                              boxShadow: [
                                new BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                                ),
                              ]),
                          child: Text("Validation Message"),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
                  Container(
                      child: Stack(
                    overflow: Overflow.visible,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 0.0,
                        top: 45.0,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 5, right: 5, top: 1, bottom: 3),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0),
                                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(5.0)),
                              boxShadow: [
                                new BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                                ),
                              ]),
                          child: Text("Validation Message"),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code - what did you already try

Comment: I have added comments in my Question

Comment: Why do you use different widget for validation message? Don't you want to use `TextFormField` with `FormFieldValidator` for this?

Comment: I can use TextFormField with FormFieldValidator, but TextformField have its own area for validation message and that will increase the space in between the TextFormFields on Submit.

I do not need that.

I need to have Validation messages overlap on the next Textfield as it sees in design

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/validation_textformfield

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize TextFormField's validator to check the String inputted on the field.

```dart
/// Initialize TextField validator message status
List<bool> _textFieldError = [false, false];

...

TextFormField(
  validator: (text) {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        /// Update boolean to determine if the validator message should be displayed
        _textFieldError[0] = true;
      });
      /// Returning a String on validator displays it as a message on the top of the TextFormField
      return '';
    }
    setState(() {
      _textFieldError[0] = false;
    });
    return null;
    },
    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
      /// Calling Form.validate() will run all validator on the Form's TextFormField children
      _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    },
  ),
  ...
)
```

Add a bool check to identify if the validator message should be displayed.

```dart
_textFieldError[0]
  ? ValidatorMessage // Display validator message
  : const SizedBox(), // Display none
```

Here's the complete code based from the repro provided.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<bool> _textFieldError = [false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("This is App Bar"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.00),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.00),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Stack(
                        overflow: Overflow.visible,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            validator: (text) {
                              if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _textFieldError[0] = true;
                                });
                                return '';
                              }
                              setState(() {
                                _textFieldError[0] = false;
                              });

                              return null;
                            },
                            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                              _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                            },
                          ),
                          _textFieldError[0]
                              ? Positioned(
                                  left: 0.0,
                                  top: 45.0,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 5, right: 5, top: 1, bottom: 3),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                            blurRadius: 5.0,
                                          ),
                                        ]),
                                    child: const Text("Validation Message"),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        child: Stack(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                      // overflow: Overflow.visible,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (text) {
                            if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                              setState(() {
                                _textFieldError[1] = true;
                              });
                              return '';
                            }
                            setState(() {
                              _textFieldError[1] = false;
                            });
                            return null;
                          },
                          onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                          },
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          left: 0.0,
                          top: 45.0,
                          child: _textFieldError[1]
                              ? Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 5, right: 5, top: 1, bottom: 3),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5.0),
                                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                                        ),
                                      ]),
                                  child: const Text("Validation Message"),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]